# Where is the location of web.xml file in CQ5.5?

Tags: aem

I wanted to know how the Servlets are mapped in CQ5.5. As in the previous version(CQ5.4) there used to be a Server folder but this seems to be changed now in this version. I searched for it in the complete cq-quickstart repository but could not find. Where can I see the web.xml file?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CQ, like in Apache Sling, you dont need a web.xml to map servlets. They are registered as components with some properties. You can use some simple annotations to register a servlet under certain resource type or path. Adobe has some [instructions](http://blogs.adobe.com/aaa/2012/09/cq-tips-and-tricks-1-how-to-define-a-slingservlet-cq5-5-5-6.html).

You Basically annotate your servlet class with the @SlingServlet annotation. You can register a servlet into a specific url or you can bind it into a particular resource type

Comment: Ok I got it the annotation @SlingServlet and giving the paths=\bin\project it is being mapped. So we do not need to write the mapping in any xml file. Thanks for the quick response !!